# IE 9 not responding to css dropdown using hover

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I have created a css only navigation menu using display:none on sub-menus and having display:block on hover but for some reason IE 9 will not display the submenu but chrome and firefox will. W3C says that IE supports :hover so I am not sure why this is not working. Here is my CSS that I am using for the menu:

```
#menu {
    position:relative;
    font:1.5em 'Calibri',sans-serif;
    color:#fff;
    list-style:none outside none;
    margin:0 auto;
    padding:0;
    width:90vw;
    text-align:center;
}

#menu li {
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0 20px;
    padding:0;
    padding-bottom:30px;
    color:#fff;
    text-align:center;
    position:relative;
}

#menu li ul {
    position:absolute;
    text-align:center;
    z-index:9999;
    top:40px;
    width:150px;
    display:none;
    padding:10px;
    left:50%;
    margin-left:-120px;
} 

#menu li:hover ul {
    display:block;
}

#menu li ul li {
    background: rgb(59,103,158); /* Old browsers */
    background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%, rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%, rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%, rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* FF3.6+ */
    background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, color-stop(0%,rgba(59,103,158,1)), color-stop(50%,rgba(43,136,217,1)), color-stop(51%,rgba(32,124,202,1)), color-stop(100%,rgba(125,185,232,1))); /* Chrome,Safari4+ */
    background: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Chrome10+,Safari5.1+ */
    background: -o-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* Opera 11.10+ */
    background: -ms-linear-gradient(top,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* IE10+ */
    background: linear-gradient(to bottom,  rgba(59,103,158,1) 0%,rgba(43,136,217,1) 50%,rgba(32,124,202,1) 51%,rgba(125,185,232,1) 100%); /* W3C */
    filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#3b679e', endColorstr='#7db9e8',GradientType=0 ); /* IE6-9 */
    text-align:center;
    border:1px solid #646464;
    width:150px;
    padding:10px;
    vertical-align: middle;
}

#menu li ul li:last-child {
    -webkit-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
    -moz-border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
    border-radius: 0 0 8px 8px;
}   

#menu li a:link {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#C2C2C2;
}

#menu li a:visited {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#C2C2C2;
}

#menu li a:hover {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}

#menu li a:active {
    text-decoration:none;
    color:#fff;
}
```

Ok so here is the html (keep in mind this is generated by Wordpress so it has extra classes and stuff added)

```
<nav class="menu-main-menu-container">
    <ul id="menu" class="menu">
        <li id="menu-item-51" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-51"><a title="Home" href="http://www.stretchmyincome.com/">Home</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-53" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-53"><a href="http://www.stretchmyincome.com/about-the-author.html">About</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-57" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-57"><a href="http://save.stretchmyincome.com/category/beauty/">Beauty</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-58" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-58"><a href="http://save.stretchmyincome.com/category/restaurants/">Restaurants</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-54" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-54"><a href="http://www.stretchmyincome.com/purchase.php">Purchase Ebook</a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-55" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children menu-item-55"><a href="http://www.stretchmyincome.com/news.html">Money News</a>
            <ul class="sub-menu">
                <li id="menu-item-59" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-59"><a href="http://save.stretchmyincome.com/category/transportation/">Transportation</a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-60" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-60"><a href="http://save.stretchmyincome.com/category/cultural/">Cultural</a>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-56" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-56"><a href="http://www.stretchmyincome.com/contact.php">Contact Us</a></li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

If anyone has any ideas as to why the sub-menus would not be showing up in IE9 that would be very helpful.

Comment: Can we see the html as well? Sounds like you forgot to close a tag or something similar

Comment: Try adding `position:relative` to `#menu li:hover ul`

Comment: tried the position:relative but that moves everything around and expands the header. The html is harder to post as it is generated by wordpress but has the general structure of ul id=menu, li, ul class=sub-menu, li

Comment: I've made a jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/9e636/1/ and that works for me in IE9. I think you need to post your html markup.

Comment: I updated the post with my html

Answer (score 0):

Have you got a valid doctype declaration? 
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp

Comment: Ok, then this is not the problem. Can you edit your question so we can see which class you're applying the hover to?

Answer (score 0):

Don't know if you already solved this, I just arrived at the office and I remember this question from yesterday. I copy/pasted you code in js fiddle and it turns out it actually has an html error, this line has no  closing tag:

```
<li id="menu-item-60" class="menu-item menu-item-type-taxonomy menu-item-object-category menu-item-has-children menu-item-60"><a href="http://save.stretchmyincome.com/category/cultural/">Cultural</a>
```

IE and the other browser handle html mistakes a little bit differently, so remember to always validate your markup! http://validator.w3.org/

Here's your fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/XeQW2/1/

And the one with the error fixed: http://jsfiddle.net/XeQW2/2/

The cause could also be something else, but this should narrow it down a little bit

Comment: Thanks for you attempt but the closing </li> was left off on accident when I copied it over on here. It is there in the live code.